# Is there a way to run MongoDB shell (or tojson method) in strict JSON mode?

Tags: json, parsing, shell, mongodb

Is there a way to run MongoDB shell (or particular tojson method) in [strict](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON) JSON mode?

Why I need this - To be able take the output of shell (generated by some js commands followed by a tojson) and convert it to JSON objects in Java.

Alternatively,

Is there any way to parse the extended JSON from shell into java Json objects? ([com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5.3/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html) expects strict JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: you can start Mongo in REST mode and the REST mode does return strict JSON. Not sure if you can access REST through the shell but it would solve your problem.

Technically there is only strict JSON, so if the to_json() method is generating invalid JSON output then I would file a bug at https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

In addition, if you would give an example of what you are trying to output using to_json() then people might be able to offer  you more specific help.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer, I appreciate it. Your first statement is not true. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON