# Mongodb- java function com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse()

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am now using java method com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(param) to convert my json string to a DBObject.I find that, in most cases , for example , when the key in the json string is simple type like string or int ,it can be used by both JSON.parse() method and terminal.
For example:

```
json string:{'times':8}
```

Both JSON.parse({'times':8}) and db.collection.find({'times':8}) in terminal can work correctly.

But when I do a query on ISODate or _id,things become different:

```
json string 1 :{'createDate':ISODate('2013-10-21T06:39:16.692Z')} 

json strign 2: {'createDate':{'$date':'2013-10-21T06:39:16.692Z'}}
```

json string 1 can work correctly in terminal but cannot be parsed by JSON.parse() method.
On the contrary , json string 2 can be parsed by JSON.parse() method but cannot be used in terminal.

The same thing happened in _id.

```
json string 3:{'_id':ObjectId('1231daf213432414321431')} 

json string 4:{'_id':{'$oid':'fadf234234sdfadfasdfa12'}}
```

json string 3 can work correctly in terminal but cannot be parsed by JSON.parse() method.
On the contrary , json string 4 can be parsed by JSON.parse() method but cannot be used in terminal.
I don't know the reason of these differences.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors you are using in the Mongo Shell are JavaScript code that is obviously not part of strict JSON that you want to parse in your Java application. The point to be criticized here is rather that the shell does not support something like '$date' (as I have just tested myself as well).

This is for example discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370206/can-strict-json-dates-be-used-in-a-mongodb-query).