# mongodb query to match date fails

Tags: mongodb

Just can't get this seemingly simple query to work. All I want to do is match records that have a specific date range (the range could be 1 for the same date). Any insight is appreciated. I have verified the collection has documents with date = "2015-11-23T09:00:00.000Z".

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find(
{ "$and" : 
    [ { "name" : { "$in" : [ "Joe", "Jane"]}} , 
    { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-11-23T09:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-11-23T09:00:00.000Z"}}}
    ]}
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frostbite,

Just change your above query to:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find(
{ 
  "$and" : 
    [ 
      { "name" : { "$in" : [ "Joe", "Jane"]}} , 
      { "date" : {
            "$gte" :ISODate("2015-11-23T09:00:00.000Z"), 
             "$lte":ISODate("2015-11-23T09:00:00.000Z")
         }
    ]
})
```

Comment: thanks much. Please can you explain why the $date is a problem.

Comment: You're Welcome! Anytime! You can read another answer about using `$date` in strict mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370206/can-strict-json-dates-be-used-in-a-mongodb-query

Comment: Also in the docs it explains that the mongo shell doesn't recognize it : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date