# Parse and import json files into mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I have some json files formatted in the following way

```
{
  <collection_name> : [
    {object}, 
    {object}
  ]
}
```

Is there any mongo script I can use to import this kind of files or a preparsing to pass in the correct format to `mongoimport`?

Update:
Using philshem's command line my input gives me the following error:

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON array is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds: offset:264
```

The date in question is

```
"uploadDate": {
  "$date": "2015-02-17T10:36:34.881Z"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard import line is:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json
```

For an array of json objects, add this flag:

```
--jsonArray
```

([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15171622/2327328))

If you tried this and it didn't work, please edit your question to include the error message.

---

**Update**: Based on the error message, check out [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24046997/2327328) and [this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date).

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly de format of date

Try this:

```
"uploadDate": {
  "$date": **ISODate(**"2015-02-17T10:36:34.881Z"**)**
}
```